# What is wrong with the mutexes in this attempt at a `std::future` implementation for C++03?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, future, c++03

I'm trying to adapt [Martinho Fernandes's sample `std::future` implementation](https://gist.github.com/rmartinho/5231565) so that it can run under C++03 with Boost 1.40, as a cheap, stop-gap measure until I can gain access to either Boost 1.41 or C++11 itself.

My adaption is hardly beautiful and it's certainly not optimal, but I was rather hoping it would at least work. However, under *gcc version 4.4.1 20090725 (Red Hat 4.4.1-2)*, it does not.

Here's `futures.h`:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
class future;

template <typename T>
class promise;

namespace detail {

    template <typename T>
    struct future_shared_state
    {
    public:

        void wait(boost::mutex& m) const
        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m, boost::adopt_lock);
            while (!(state || error))
                available.wait(lock);
        }

        T& get()
        {
            if (state)
                return *state;

            if (error)
                throw *error;

            throw std::runtime_error("WTF");
        }

        template <typename U>
        void set_value(const U& value)
        {
            state = value;
            available.notify_all();
        }

        void set_exception(boost::shared_ptr<std::exception> e)
        {
            error = e;
            available.notify_all();
        }

    private:
        mutable boost::condition_variable available;
        boost::optional<T> state;
        boost::shared_ptr<std::exception> error;

        friend class promise<T>;
        friend class future<T>;
        mutable boost::mutex m;
    };

}

template <typename T>
struct future
{
public:
    future() {}
    ~future() {}

    T get()
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<detail::future_shared_state<T> > old_box;
        swap(box, old_box);

        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(old_box->m);
        old_box->wait(old_box->m);
        return old_box->get();
    }

    bool valid() const
    {
        return !!box;
    }

    void wait() const
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(box->m);
        box->wait(box->m);
    }

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<detail::future_shared_state<T> > box;

    friend class promise<T>;
    future(boost::shared_ptr<detail::future_shared_state<T> > const& box) : box(box) {}
};

template <typename T>
struct promise
{
public:
    promise() : box(new detail::future_shared_state<T>) {}
    ~promise() {}   

    void swap(promise& other)
    {
        box.swap(other.box);
    }

    future<T> get_future()
    {
        return future<T>(box);
    }

    void set_value(T const& value)
    {
        box->set_value(value);
    }

    void set_exception(boost::shared_ptr<std::exception> e)
    {
        box->set_exception(e);
    }

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<detail::future_shared_state<T> > box;
};

template<typename T>
void swap(promise<T>& lhs, promise<T>& rhs)
{
    lhs.swap(rhs);
}
```

And the execution:

```
#include "futures.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void foo(promise<unsigned int> p)
{
    sleep(1);
    p.set_value(42);
}

int main()
{
    promise<unsigned int> p;
    future <unsigned int> f(p.get_future());

    boost::thread t(&foo, p);
    std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;

    t.join();
}

// g++ -O0 -g test.cpp -lboost_thread -pthread -o test
```

The result, consistently, is the following:

```
42
test: /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:45: boost::mutex::~mutex(): Assertion `!pthread_mutex_destroy(&m)' failed.
Aborted
```

Backtrace from gdb:

```
#0  0x00679422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x002ac781 in *__GI_raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#2  0x002ae04a in *__GI_abort () at abort.c:88
#3  0x002a58de in *__GI___assert_fail (assertion=0x805de56 "!pthread_mutex_destroy(&m)",
    file=0x805de24 "/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp", line=45, function=0x805e071 "boost::mutex::~mutex()")
    at assert.c:78
#4  0x0804bdd5 in boost::mutex::~mutex (this=0x806c9c0, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
    at /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:45
#5  0x0804d020 in detail::future_shared_state<unsigned int>::~future_shared_state (this=0x806c980,
    __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at futures.h:35
#6  0x0804d099 in boost::checked_delete<detail::future_shared_state<unsigned int> > (x=0x806c980)
    at /usr/local/include/boost/checked_delete.hpp:34
#7  0x0804d69c in boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<detail::future_shared_state<unsigned int> >::dispose (this=0x806c9e0)
    at /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_impl.hpp:78
#8  0x0804bb68 in boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release (this=0x806c9e0)
    at /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:145
#9  0x0804bbfe in boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count (this=0xbffff634, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
    at /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:217
#10 0x0804c2d4 in boost::shared_ptr<detail::future_shared_state<unsigned int> >::~shared_ptr (this=0xbffff630,
    __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:169
#11 0x0804c535 in promise<unsigned int>::~promise (this=0xbffff630, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at futures.h:125
#12 0x0804b937 in main () at test.cpp:19
```

**Awful style aside, what am I doing wrong with my mutexes?**

Comment: Which OS are you running on?

Comment: Which version of g++ are you using? I'm unable to reproduce with 4.5.

Comment: Also, error on line 47 in test.cpp indicates there are more lines in your main.cpp than the one shown. Could you indicate which line in main.cpp the termination happens on? I'm guessing after `join`, but I'd rather not guess.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson Even without seeing the code I'm willing to bet it's the closing `}` of `main`, causing the destructors to be called.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yeah I think Mark is right. It's a verbatim minimal testcase (though I never 100% rule out mistakes in the process of posting it!)

Comment: @MarkB: Pretty old; GCC 4.4.1 if memory serves, but I'd have to check once I'm back at my desk.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Oh, yes, I executed it with some commented out gubbins above `main`; whoops.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Now corrected.

Comment: @MarkB: Added environment details to question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are data races on `future_shared_state::value` and `future_shared_state::error`, `set_value` and `set_exception` access them without acquiring the mutex that `wait` uses to guard them.

The actual problem you are experiencing is due to your use of `boost::mutex::scoped_lock` in the callers of `future_shared_state::wait`: you successfully avoid locking the mutex twice with `adopt_lock` inside `future_shared_state::wait`, but both of the `scoped_lock` destructors run and unlock the mutex twice.

Both problems are easily fixed by making the locking all internal to `future_shared_state` ([Demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3efdefe51e3a475)):

```
namespace detail {

    template <typename T>
    struct future_shared_state
    {
    public:

        void wait() const
        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);
            while (!(state || error))
                available.wait(lock);
        }

        T& get()
        {
            if (state)
                return *state;

            if (error)
                throw *error;

            throw std::runtime_error("WTF");
        }

        template <typename U>
        void set_value(const U& value)
        {
            {
                boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);
                state = value;
            }
            available.notify_all();
        }

        void set_exception(boost::shared_ptr<std::exception> e)
        {
            {
                boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);
                error = e;
            }
            available.notify_all();
        }

    private:
        mutable boost::condition_variable available;
        boost::optional<T> state;
        boost::shared_ptr<std::exception> error;

        mutable boost::mutex m;
    };

}

template <typename T>
class promise;

template <typename T>
struct future
{
public:
    future() {}
    ~future() {}

    T get()
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<detail::future_shared_state<T> > old_box;
        swap(box, old_box);

        old_box->wait();
        return old_box->get();
    }

    bool valid() const
    {
        return !!box;
    }

    void wait() const
    {
        box->wait();
    }

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<detail::future_shared_state<T> > box;

    friend class promise<T>;
    future(boost::shared_ptr<detail::future_shared_state<T> > const& box) : box(box) {}
};

template <typename T>
struct promise
{
public:
    promise() : box(new detail::future_shared_state<T>) {}
    ~promise() {}   

    void swap(promise& other)
    {
        box.swap(other.box);
    }

    future<T> get_future()
    {
        return future<T>(box);
    }

    void set_value(T const& value)
    {
        box->set_value(value);
    }

    void set_exception(boost::shared_ptr<std::exception> e)
    {
        box->set_exception(e);
    }

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<detail::future_shared_state<T> > box;
};
```

Comment: Pure style issue: I'd make the other `future` constructor public and get rid of the friend and forward declarations of `promise`.

Comment: That makes sense; I think the original code was that way so alternative locks could be set up (timed ones, and whatnot).

Comment: Thanks @Casey; this is working now and I understand why.